# Accessing Submenu Items in Electron

Tags: menu, electron

I would like to access the submenu elements in my menu.

My menu is organized like:

```
 File
    --stuff
 Workflow
    --item 1
    --item 2
 Help
    --stuff
```

And the code that I have right now

```
    var workflowItem = items.filter(function findWorkflowMenu(menuItem) {
        return menuItem.label === 'Workflow'
    })

    if( workflowItem.length > 0 ) {
        console.log('workflow item: ' )
        console.log(workflowItem[0].menu.items) //this line doesn't seem right
    }
```

The console output is showing all the menu again and not the sub-elements to Workflow.

What is the proper query to get the sub elements?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should be:

```
const {Menu} = require('electron');

let menu = new Menu([
   'label': 'menu item',
     'submenu': [{
       'label': 'aLabel'        
    }]
}]);


console.log(menu[0].submenu);
```

If you can't get this to work on your app it means you have some problems in your filter or somewhere else.